# How do labels and dd declarations work in NASM? What's the C equivalent?

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to understand what'd be the C equivalent of some nasm idioms like these ones:

```
%define CONSTANT1 1
%define CONSTANT2 2

1) section name_section data align=N
    v1: dd 1.2345678
    v2: dd 0x12345678
    v3: dd 32767
    v4:
    v5: dd 1.0
    v6:
        dd 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
        dd 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0

2) section name_section bss align=N
    v7:
        resd 1

3) global _function_name@0
    section name_section code align=N
    _function_name@0:
        ...

4) global _g_structure1
    global _g_structure2
    section name_section data align=N
    _g_structure1:
        dw 01h
        dw 2
    _g_structure2:
        dd CONSTANT1
        dd CONSTANT2

5) section section_name code align=N
    function_name:
        ...
```

The nasm documentation [here](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html) and [here](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html) didn't clarify too much. Guess my questions are:

- How `dd` and similars are interpreted?
- It seems you can declare N sections of type {code, bss, data} with X bytes alignment, what's the meaning of that in C?
- There are functions with the @N suffix, what's the meaning of that?
- global... you declare global labels? in what scope? nasm files?
- v4: is empty, what does that mean?

Comment: You last question: `v4` and `v5` are labels with the same value, since there was nothing generated at `v4`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see, nice, what about v6? Is that an array of DWORDS or something?

Comment: With `v6` there is only whitespace separating it from the memory definition, which could be an array as you say.

Comment: @WeatherVane Alright, tyvm

Comment: About v1-v6 labels: they are more like `(void *)` at the first byte of next machine code produced. They don't need that `dd` coming, whatever directive/instruction defines next byte value, that will be where that label is pointing at. So while not practical for defining numerical values, these two **are** equivalent: `labelX: dd 0x05b3448a` == `labelX: mov al,[ebx+esi*4+0x5]` (that instruction will produce machine code 4 bytes long with the same value as the `dd` .. and the "labelX" thus points at the same first byte 0x8a followed by the other three.

Comment: You should ask a separate question for each question you have here and not lump them all into one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dd` stores a sequence of `DWORDS` given by the arguments. So `dd 1` will store the 4-byte value 0x00000001 at the current location (since it's targeting a little endian architecture, you'll end up with the bytes `0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00`).

Sections aren't generally exposed directly in C - it's more of a lower level concern handled by compilers, linkers and runtime loaders. So *in general* your toolchain will handle the proper allocation of your code and data into sections. For example, the compiler will put the actual assembled code into `.text` sections, and will put statically initialized data into `.data` sections, and finally will put uninitialized or zero-initialized statically allocated data into `.bss` sections, and so on. The details aren't really part of C itself and will vary by platform and executable format (for example, not all platforms have the same types of sections).

When using assembly, on the other hand, you need to be a bit more aware of sections. For example, if you have mutable data it is important that it ends up a different section than your code, since you don't want to run into read-only `.text` sections, or self-modifying-code false positives, etc.

The section alignment is a directive to the runtime loader that tells it the minimum required alignment for the section. You can impact this in your C code using some compiler or platform specific options - e.g. if you request a statically allocated array to have an alignment of 32, then the `.data` section may be promoted to at least 32-byte alignment. C doesn't have a standard way to actually request such alignment, but you can use platform specific extensions such as [`posix_memalign`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html), gcc's [`aligned`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) attribute, or even `#pragma pack`. C++11 on the other hand has [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/alignas) to do this in a standard way.

The `@N` suffix is a result of [`stdcall name mangling`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C).

You can declare global labels with the help of the `GLOBAL` directive in nasm. As Peter point out, this only modifies the attributes of a subsequently declared label, and doesn't actually declare the label itself (which is still done in the usual way). This directive has other [format-specific options](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.6) which let you, for example, declare your exported symbol as a function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). What about v6, v7 and _g_structure1? what'd be the c equivalent of that? Also, is it ok whether I add more questions to the current question instead opening more newbie-threads like this one?

Comment: @BPL please stick to the question you have asked - these questions are not a continually shifting dialog.

Comment: Yeah... create a new question if you have new questions. In fact, it's kind of better to create a short simple question for each query you have rather than mashing them all together. It makes it more searchable and allows people to answer the ones they know the most about, etc...

Comment: @BPL - yes, the bad title is a consequence of combining many questions into one - now there is no good title to cover them all! Open additional questions, one per question with titles like "What does `dd` do in NASM?", "How are global structures declared in NASM?" etc.

Comment: That's fine, but I'm not sure how it relates to the feedback on your question? Regardless of the level you want to get to in asm, the recommendations for how to structure your SO questions are the same.

Comment: re: alignment: Even though this is a C question, maybe worth mentioning that ISO C++11 introduced the `alignas()` keyword, so you can write `alignas(32) double simd_array[1024];`.  C11 does not have any similar feature, AFAIK, so in C you still have to keep using `__declspec` or `__attribute__((aligned(32)))` or whatever. :(

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: C11 introduces the equivalent `_Alignas`, and with `#include <stdalign.h>` you can use the same `alignas(32)` as in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

The NASM `global label` directive does not actually declare `label`.  It just modifies what scope it will have when you do declare it, with `label:`.

It's the opposite of C, where global is the default and you have to use `static` to get non-exported symbols that are private to this compilation unit.

---

> `v4:` is empty, what does that mean?

Think of labels as zero-width pointers.  The label itself has no size, it just labels that position in the binary.  (And you can have multiple labels at the same location).

NASM has no types, so it's really quite similar to `void*`.

Comment: I see, what about v6, v7 and g_structure1? I've been told v6 would be the equivalent to a dword c-array (all dd values are separated by ','). What about g_structure1? Is that a c-struct?

Comment: @BPL: yes, structs in C are a good choice for describing a bunch of related bytes in a contiguous chunk of memory, which is the same thing that asm is doing.  Look at compiler output for a static `struct`, for example.

Comment: I guess I can't rely too much on VS's asm listings, it's masm syntax and it's not the same one than nasm :(, look [here](http://screencast.com/t/IslARbWyOKG7)

Comment: @BPL: it still uses DB, DW, DD, and DQ.  All x86 assembly languages just assemble bytes into a file.  At the level of labels and data, they're pretty much the same.  But anyway, if you don't like MSVC's MASM syntax, then use something else.  (Although your realistic options are gcc and clang, on your computer or on http://gcc.godbolt.org/, and their GNU-style `-masm=intel` output is more like MASM than NASM, and uses very different directives than NASM.)

Comment: Ok, clear, thanks! One last question, what's wrong with this [hello world](http://content.screencast.com/users/bpedrosa/folders/Jing/media/4082eaed-b279-4e4d-a5a6-58b60fbe6785/2016-11-06_2221.png) example? Also, is there any chat/room for these type of newbie questions? I wouldn't like to pollute SO with these type of dummy questions :P

Comment: @BPL.  You probably forgot to link with the right DLLs, but IDK, I don't use Windows.

Comment: @BPL - FWIW, you aren't _polluting_ SO when you ask clear, straightforward questions even when they are at "newbie" level (indeed, such questions will often already be answered while you are composing them as SO recommends similar questions). The whole idea of some kind of private chat where people can do what amounts to unpaid tutoring for users, without helping anyone else in the progress is kind of antithetical to SO - the idea is that every question can help others who have the same issue, and that more answers can be added in the future if things change or smarter people come along.