# "label or instruction expected at start of line" error with online complier for assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I tried to compile the following codes using an online compiler.

[image]

This is the code:

```
section .data
    EAX:12131415h
    EDX:12345678h
    
section .code
_start:
    Rol EAX, 16
    Rol EAH, 8
    Rol EAL, 8
    Rol EDX, 16
    Rol EDH,  8
    Rol EDL, 8
Int 21h
.end
```

This is the error that I got:
[image]

**Does anyone know how to fix this error?**

This is the problem that I tried to answer:

We have an 8 bytes width number, so we save the lower bytes in EAX and higher bytes in EDX: for example number 1234567812131415h will be saved like EAX = 12131415h, EDX = 12345678h. Write a general-purpose program that is able to reverses any number 8 bytes width number that its least significant bytes are in EAX and its most significant bytes are saved in EDX . Note: Reverse means that our sample number becomes: EAX=78563412h and EDX = 15141312h.

Comment: There are no such registers as `EAH, EAL, EDH, EDL`.  See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-Purpose_Registers_(GPR)_-_16-bit_naming_conventions, especially the table "identifiers to access registers and parts thereof".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code? It doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Oh, and it looks like the `mycompiler.io` x86-64 asm mode runs its programs on 64-bit Linux.  Your `Int 21h` is a 16-bit MS-DOS API and won't work at all.

Comment: I updated the question with the problem that I tried to solve.

Comment: I tested the code by changing line 2 and 3 with `EAX$:12131415h` and `EDX$:12345678h`. I got the following errors for both: `error: parser: instruction expected`

Comment: This is the online compiler that I used https://www.mycompiler.io/new/asm-x86_64

Comment: EAX is a legal label name in NASM, but you can only declare it with `$EAX:`.  You can load from it with `mov eax, [$EAX]` to disambiguate from the reg name.  Unlike `loop:`, the `:` doesn't force treating as a label instead of a reg name.  (You can use `nm` to verify that actual symbol name is EAX, not `$EAX`, so you could interoperate with a C `int EAX;` global var.)  The other problem is `label: number` without a DD directive; possibly the OP thought that would initialize registers. (To set up for their emulation of bswap eax and bswap edx using the wrong register names for AH and so on.)

Comment: @hongkongbboy: yes, did you miss the rest of my comment (which I reposted to clean up other parts, not the part about needing `dd`)?  `label: number` isn't valid, you need `label: dd number`.  `dd` is the "instruction" in that line which is missing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I haven't learned how to use `dd` and apply `$` symbol yet.

Comment: You don't really want to mess around with `$EAX` symbol names, just use label names that aren't the same as registers.  As for using `dd`, you need to understand that if you want to put static data in memory.  See [How do labels and dd declarations work in NASM? What's the C equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40453482), the first duplicate.  (Of course, `mov eax, 0x12345678` at the start of your code would avoid having to load from memory.)